# Ruby float with double 0

Tags: ruby, floating-point, decimal, zero

When printing floats, ruby prints `1234.0` with only one `0` after the period. How can I force ruby to print two `0`s?

Comment: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/formatting-dates-and-floats-in-ruby/

Comment: Note that when dealing with concrete and important values like currency, you may not want to store them in something as inexact as a Float. Instead, store the number of the smallest units of money as Integers (for example, $1.34 in US currency would be stored as 134), or use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/classes/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Format strings to the rescue:

```
>> puts "%.2f" % 1.0 #=> nil
1.00
```